# Dynamic filters with power bi reports

Tags: powerbi

I have a very big database with a lot of tables. Let’s imagine this is Amazon customer database.

I have several users which want to make queries on this database. For example : « give me all customers which live in this area, are between 20 and 30 years old, have spent between 200 ans 300$ in 2017 and which did not made any order last 6 month and which visited product pages talking about video games last 3 days  ».

Queries can concern every table and every field. I do not Know at development step which criteria will be needed by users. It can change every day.

What i need is to provide an universal query tool.

I have deployed power bi and i need to add dynamic filters inside the report but i do not know how...

My problem is i want to embed filters INSIDE the report

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Do you need a Power BI tutorial on filters?

Comment: No, my problem is that filters should be dynamics

Comment: Describe what that is in your world. Power BI slicers filter data when the user clicks them. Charts cross-filter each other. Is that not dynamic?

Comment: My problem is i want to embed filters INSIDE the report

Comment: I guess you need to explain your requirements a bit more. When the user opens the report, what do you expect to happen that will apply filters? Do users click somewhere? How would Power BI know what to filter?

Comment: The user should add any filter he wants inside the report. He may have a plus button to add a new filter row and several  combobox on each row (table, fields, comparison expression, value, checkboxes, etc)

Comment: Filters are created in Power BI desktop. The user can then apply filters in the filter panel of the published report. But they cannot dynamically add new fields to filter, if these have not been set up in the desktop.

Comment: Is there a kind of sdk ? If so I would develop a kind of custom power bi desktop (in a web page if possible)